# How do I get past SSRS Login when recording using JMeter?

Tags: reporting-services, jmeter, ssrs-2012

I am attempting to create some JMeter tests for our SSRS reports, but I cannot get past the initial login. I login and press ok and it continues to display this login dialog.

[image: auth]

It records an HTTP Authorization Manager element.

[image]

How can I get past this and continue on to my reports?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a windows server and you don't need this authentication prompt then you can use below approach( in case you are okay with direct login with windows credentials):

1. Open up Server Manager. It should open by default when you access your instance, but if not you can pull this up by going to your Start button -> All Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Server Manager.
2. Once in the Server Manager you will see under the Security Information an option for Configure IE ESC.
3. You can choose to Enable/Disable it for just the Administrator account or for all User accounts.

Then the prompt will not be there if you reopen the browser.

You can refer this in case of doubt: https://community.hpcloud.com/article/how-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-your-windows-instance

Comment: Unfortunately I am not running on windows server. This is on a windows 7 machine.